# bash builtin commands in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

Following rule to clean all the binary files in the makefile doesn't work.

```
SHELL:=bash
PHONY: clean
clean:
    for file in {"greedy","mario","pset1_mario","credit","hello"}; do \
        [[ -e "${file}" ]] && rm ${file}; \
    done
```

It gives following error message.

```
recipe for target 'clean' failed make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

It works if I invoke another shell script with the same command from the make file.

```
clean:
    bash ./cleanup.sh
```

Is there a way I can put these commands inside the makefile itself?

Comment: You need two dollar signs on the variables: `$${file}` in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Error 1` isn't what you think it is.

Use `SHELL:=/bin/bash -x` in the makefile and you'll see that you aren't running what you expect to be running.

Specifically you forgot to escape the `$` in the recipe from make so instead of testing each name in that list in the `-e` test you are testing the empty string (`[ -e "" ]`). This then fails each time through the loop.

The *last* time through the loop when that fails the `for` loop ends and since the last command in the loop exited with a failure return the entire loop ends with a failure return so make sees the script ending with a failure and reports that.

You want this:

```
SHELL:=bash
.PHONY: clean
clean:
        for file in {"greedy","mario","pset1_mario","credit","hello"}; do \
            [[ ! -e "$${file}" ]] || rm $${file}; \
        done
```

Note the double `$$` on the shell variables and note the inversion of the test and conditional. make recipe lines need to return success unless you want them to terminate the make.

Also note `.PHONY` there. `PHONY` is just a normal target.

Update:

It is probably also worth pointing out that this snippet specifically gains nothing from the brace expansion or bash-specific `[[` test and could just as easily be rewritten in a sh-compatible manner:

```
clean:
        for file in greedy mario pset1_mario credit hello; do \
            [ ! -e "$${file}" ] || rm $${file}; \
        done
```

Comment: ...and the whole concept "remove if exists, otherwise silently ignore" is exactly what `rm -f` does anyway